# draw random element in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cumsum

I have an array of element probabilities, let's say `[0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2]`. The array sums up to 1.0.

Using plain Python or numpy, I want to draw elements proportional to their probability: the first element about 10% of the time, second 20%, third 50% etc. The "draw" should return index of the element drawn.

I came up with this:

```
def draw(probs):
    cumsum = numpy.cumsum(probs / sum(probs)) # sum up to 1.0, just in case
    return len(numpy.where(numpy.random.rand() >= cumsum)[0])
```

It works, but it's too convoluted, there must be a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
def random_pick(choices, probs):
    '''
    >>> a = ['Hit', 'Out']
    >>> b = [.3, .7]
    >>> random_pick(a,b)
    '''
    cutoffs = np.cumsum(probs)
    idx = cutoffs.searchsorted(np.random.uniform(0, cutoffs[-1]))
    return choices[idx]
```

---

**How it works:**

```
In [22]: import numpy as np
In [23]: probs = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2]
```

Compute the cumulative sum:

```
In [24]: cutoffs = np.cumsum(probs)
In [25]: cutoffs
Out[25]: array([ 0.1,  0.3,  0.8,  1. ])
```

Compute a uniformly distributed random number in the half-open interval `[0, cutoffs[-1])`:

```
In [26]: np.random.uniform(0, cutoffs[-1])
Out[26]: 0.9723114393023948
```

Use [searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy-searchsorted) to find the index where the random number would be inserted into `cutoffs`:

```
In [27]: cutoffs.searchsorted(0.9723114393023948)
Out[27]: 3
```

Return `choices[idx]`, where `idx` is that index.

Answer (score 4):

You want to sample from the categorical distribution, which is not implemented in numpy. However, the [multinomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) distribution is a generalization of the [categorical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) distribution and can be used for that purpose.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> def sampleCategory(p):
...     return np.flatnonzero( np.random.multinomial(1,p,1) )[0]
... 
>>> sampleCategory( [0.1,0.5,0.4] )
1
```

Answer (score 1):

use `numpy.random.multinomial` - most efficient

Answer (score 0):

I've never used numpy, but I assume my code below (python only) does the same thing as what you accomplished in one line. I'm putting it here just in case you want it.

Looks very c-ish so apologies for not being very pythonic.

weight_total would be 1 for you.

```
def draw(probs)
    r = random.randrange(weight_total)
    running_total = 0
    for i, p in enumerate(probs)
        running_total += p
        if running_total > r:
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

use [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html)

```
import bisect
import random
import numpy 
def draw(probs):
    cumsum=numpy.cumsum(probs/sum(probs))
    return bisect.bisect_left(cumsum, numpy.random.rand())
```

should do the trick.